# Variable number of nested loops with head and tail

Tags: java, recursion

I have these nested for loops:

```
void fun() {

    int n = 5;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        head_function(i, c);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            head_function(j, c);
            for (int w = 0; w < n; w++) {
                head_function(w, c);
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                    head_function(x, c);

                    c++;
                    body(c);

                    tail_function(x, c);
                }
                tail_function(w, c);
            }
            tail_function(j, c);
        }
        tail_function(i, c);
    }
}
```

It doesn't really matter what the head and tail functions do, as long as they can keep track of their indices i, j, w, x.

What I want is to have an arbitrary number of nested for loops instead of just four.

The other solutions I found here didn't really work for me, because they did not include the head and tail functions, I guess.

Comment: Use a recursive method and a recursion depth as parameter.

Comment: Recursion is recommended against, because most hardware treats stack memory specially, and unneeded recursion tends to use more stack memory than other methods.  You can use a single loop, and an array to keep an arbitrary number of indexes.  It's more complicated to code but if your "depth" is large it would be better to code it that way.

Comment: @markspace Now that is premature optimization for you. One should write clear concise code and recursion is natural here and if OP is 4 deep he can double it many times before it becomes a problem. You can even prolonge the fix by increasing the VMs stack memory.

Comment: I disagree; recursion should almost always be converted to loops.  VM memory has nothing to do with this; it's the stack memory in the CPU that gets overflowed, and rather quickly.  If the OP stack never gets more than 4 or 5 deep, sure they're fine.  But often this sort of problem grows quickly.

Comment: @markspace It's not limited in the CPU. For java you just pass `-Xss` and you get inscreased stack memory in the VM. Java stack is not the same as the java applications stack so it's a whole different heap-allocated area I guess. For gcc you pass `--stack` when you compile. The stack is registers pointed to the the end of the assigned memory size. A stack overflow is when you get a MMU error from going below the lowest allowed index of the **specified** area.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a skeleton to get you started. Feel free to add params and change signatures according to your needs.

```
public void doStuffRecursively(int nTimes){
    doIt(nTimes);
}

void doIt(int depth){
    if(depth==0)
        body();
    else{
        head(depth);
        doIt(depth-1);
        tail(depth);
    }
}

void body(){}

void head(int depth){}
void tail(int depth){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-recursive version that iterates over a single array of loop indices.

You're code as a bit of a niggle in it: the innermost loop is different from the other loops in that only it calls `body()` and increments the general counter.  I accounted for this by checking inside my loop for the "inner loop" which is indicated by the `loop` variable being 0.

I also changed your `n` from 5 to 3 (`max`), just to reduce the size of the output.  The rest of the code I think is pretty straight forward.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\n Loop 1\n");
        loop( 1 );
        System.out.println("\n Loop 2\n");
        loop( 2 );
        System.out.println("\n Loop 3\n");
        loop( 3 );
    }

    public static void loop( int depth ) {
        int[] indices = new int[depth];
        final int max = 3;
        int count = 0;
        for( int x = 0; x < depth - 1; x++ )
            head( x, count );
        outer:
        for(;;) {
            for( int loop = 0; loop < indices.length; loop++ ) {
                if( indices[loop] < max ) {
                    head( indices[loop], count );
                    if( loop == 0 ) {
                        count++;
                        body( indices[loop], count );
                    }
                    tail( indices[loop], count );
                    indices[loop]++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    if( loop == indices.length - 1 ) break outer;
                    indices[loop] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void head( int index, int counter ) {
        System.out.printf( "head index=%d count=%d%n", index, counter );
    }
    private static void body( int index, int counter ) {
        System.out.printf( "body index=%d count=%d%n", index, counter );
    }
    private static void tail( int index, int counter ) {
        System.out.printf( "tail index=%d count=%d%n", index, counter );
    }

}
```

Partial output (it gets rather long):

```
 Loop 1

head index=0 count=0
body index=0 count=1
tail index=0 count=1
head index=1 count=1
body index=1 count=2
tail index=1 count=2
head index=2 count=2
body index=2 count=3
tail index=2 count=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since n seems to be always the same, you can try (c is now a private field, n is the number of the nested for loops):

```
private int c;

void loopAtDepth(int depth){
    if( depth == 0){
       c++;
       body(c);
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            head_function(i, c);
            loopAtDepth(depth - 1)
            tail_function(i, c);
        }
    }
}
```